# Tkinter anchor option not working with multiline string

Tags: python, tkinter, label, anchor

I'd like to have a label in my GUI where text is left aligned. I tryied to use `anchor` but it doesn't seem to work, if the string consists of multiple lines.
My code looks as follows:

```
lbl_welcome = tk.Label(fr_welcome, anchor = 'w', text = "First line\n and this is the second")
```

The label and frame are positioned to the north west, using `sticky`.
What I get looks like this:
[GUI with the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fr4J.png)

Here the label/textbox is aligned to the left, but not the text itself. It works fine however with a single-line string, where `\n` is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default each line is centered. You need to use the `justify` option if you want the text left-justified.

```
lbl_welcome = tk.Label(..., justify="left")
```

[image: screenshot]